# Enviar fila por fila sin duplicados

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven hay una columna llamada **Integration** de tipo bool, toda esta tabla la muestro en un **DataGridView** por medio de procedimiento almacenado que es este

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Pagos]
AS 
SELECT 'CE-'+CardCode AS CardCode,DocType,Series,DocDate,dbo.udf_GetNumeric(DocNum) AS DocNum,
DocEntry,TrsfrAcct,TrsfrDate,TrsfrSum, Integration,Comments,SumApplied
FROM  PaymentsReceived WHERE Integration = 0
```

Este SP le digo que solo me muestre los que están en 0 es decir en false, lo que hago ya con los que están en false es enviarlos por un web services, tengo un método que recorre cada fila y la va enviando y cada vez que hace un envió la pone en true, entonces desaparece del DataGridView, este método esta dentro de un timer que se dispara cada 5 segundos, En este método hay una condición que dice si **Integration** es == a false entonces déjelo enviar,    este es el método.

```
private async void Envio_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ProxyBL proxy = new ProxyBL();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow Datos in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    PagosRecibidos pagos = new PagosRecibidos
                    {
                        CardCode = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[0].Value),
                        DocType = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[1].Value),
                        Series = Convert.ToInt32(Datos.Cells[2].Value),
                        DocDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Datos.Cells[3].Value),
                        DocEntry = Convert.ToInt32(Datos.Cells[5].Value),
                        TrsfrAcct = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[6].Value),
                        TrsfrDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Datos.Cells[7].Value),
                        TrsfrSum = Convert.ToDecimal(Datos.Cells[8].Value),
                        Integration = Convert.ToBoolean(Datos.Cells[9].Value),
                        Comments = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[10].Value),
                        SumApplied = Convert.ToDecimal(Datos.Cells[11].Value)
                    };
                    Inte = pagos.Integration;
                    if (Inte == false)
                    {
                        var EnvioDatos = await proxy.EnviarPago(pagos);
                    }
                    ListarEmple();
                    ListarLog();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Este es el método donde entra  **EnviarPago**

Este método obtengo la respuesta del Services, donde si
la operación fue exitosa o fallo me inserta esto en un Log

```
Consultas c = new Consultas();

        public async Task<string> EnviarPago(PagosRecibidos detalle)
        {
            try
            {
                ProxyXML xmlProxy = new ProxyXML();
                string respuesta = await xmlProxy.EnviarSAP(detalle);
                c.InsertarLog(1, DateTime.Now, respuesta, xmlProxy.XmlSerializado);
                return respuesta;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Luego de este método entra ya al envió, **EnviaSAP**

Que es donde capturo la respuesta, si la operación fue exitosa entonces mérqueme la columna **Integration** como "1 true"

```
 readonly Consultas c = new Consultas();  
        public string XmlSerializado = null;

        public async Task<string> EnviarSAP(PagosRecibidos detalle)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WSSincronizacionClient clienteSAP = new WSSincronizacionClient())
                {
                    XmlSerializado = this.SerializarXml(detalle);
                    var respuesta = await clienteSAP.EnviarDatosSAPAsync(XmlSerializado);
                    if (respuesta.Contains("true|Operación Exitosa|"))
                    {
                        c.EditarIntegration(true, Convert.ToInt32(detalle.DocEntry));
                    }
                    return respuesta;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Todo funciona correctamente pero al hacer el envió a veces lo envía doble o duplicado es decir que en SAP llega dos veces, como puedo hacer esta validación, de que solo me pase solo una vez el que esta en false, que por nada me lo envié dos veces y en que parte debería hacer esta validación

Tampoco se por que si ya tiene esa validación de que solo envié los que están false igual lo envía dos veces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando trabajas con Timers, debes tener presente que un evento `Tick` se puede disparar antes de que termine uno que ya está en ejecución.

Cuando esto ocurre, tendrás al menos 2 procesos actuando sobre el mismo conjunto de datos y es por eso que ocasionalmente se envían duplicados.

Una opción que yo utilizo para casos similares es detener el timer mientras se ejecuta un evento `Tick` y activarlo al terminar.

El siguiente ejemplo omite parte de tu código para mantener el enfóque en el área de interés:

```
private async void Envio_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Hacer un cast del sender, para detener el timer
    Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
    timer.Stop();


    try
    {
        ProxyBL proxy = new ProxyBL();

        // ...código omitido ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        // Este bloque se agrega para garantizar que el timer se vuelva a activar
        // aún en caso de error

        //Activar el timer
        timer.Start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Pero en finally solo meto el time.Start?

Comment: Si. El bloque `finally` no lo utilizas en tu código original y la razón para agregarlo es garantizar que el timer se active aún en casos de error. Puedes ver más información relacionada con el `try-finally` [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally)

Comment: Al parecer funciona correctamente gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un método que valide duplicados

```html
List<Object> ValidateDuplicate(List<object> lstPrincipal){
   List<Object> _lst = new List<Object>();

  foreach(var i as lstPrincipal){
    
     if(_lst.where(x.validate == i.validate).coun ==0){
        _lst.add(i)
      }
  }

return _lts
    
}
```

Comment: No creo que validar duplicados le sirva de mucho si tienes dos procesos enviando el mismo objeto a la vez... puesto que en ambos casos te dirá que no está duplicado, dado que todavía se está enviando